# Put border in empty progress bar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar, border

I am using Bootstrap Progress Bar. My Code is like below

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to put border in above Progress Bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!-- bootstrap.min.css -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="progress border border-success">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Please add [border](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) class in bootstrap

Also add color too

- `border-success`
- `border-info`
- `border-danger`
- `border-warning`
- `border-secondary`
- `border-primary`
- `border-white` etc

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you're asking for the upper div or the `actual` progress bar, but I have given it for both:

```css
.progress {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width:50%;border:2px solid red;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Manjuboyz. Yes, I am asking for the `actual` progress bar. Your code is working but I need border with `width:0%`. Code will be `<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="border:2px solid red;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>`. How can I get that border ?

Comment: Then the `border` is not for `progress-bar` it should be to parent div: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/v4j037d2/23/ when the progress bar increases then you can add your own border as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="progress border border-info">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```